# How to set Deep copy in copy constructor?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I need to set my copy constructor to deep copy on my point and segment class but I am not sure if I did it right or no. Can anyone help?

```java
public class Segment implements SegmentInterface {
    // two Points that hold endpoints of the segment
    private Point p1;
    private Point p2;

    // Default constructor that will set the endpoints to new
    // Points with values (0,0) and (4,4)
    public Segment() {
        //this(0, 0, 4, 4);
        this.p1 = new Point(0, 0);
        this.p2 = new Point(4, 4);
    }

    // Parameterized constructor that accepts (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    // and creates and sets the endpoints
    public Segment(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        //this.p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
        //this.p2 = new Point(x2, y2);

        if(x1 != x2 && y1 != y2){
            this.p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
            this.p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
        } 

        else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("undefined");
    }
}

    // Parameterized constructor that accepts (Point p1, Point p2) and sets both
    // the endpoints to a deep copy of the Points that are passed in.

    public Segment(Point p1, Point p2) {

        if(p1 != p2){
        this.p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
        this.p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
        }       
            else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Points cannot have same values!");
            } 
}

    // Copy constructor that accepts a Segment and initializes the data (of the
    // new Segment being created) to be the same as the Segment that was
    // received.
    public Segment(Segment other) {

            this.p1 = other.p1;
            this.p2 = other.p2;
}
```

Please consider that this is not the whole code!

My Point class is:

```java
public class Point implements PointInterface {

    // hold the x-value and the y-value of the Point
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    // default constructor that will set the values to (0, 0)
    public Point() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    // parameterized constructor that will receive 2 ints (first the x
    // coordinate and then the y)
    // and set the data variables to the values received.
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // A copy constructor that will receive a Point and then initializes the
    // data
    // Deep Copy
    public Point(Point other) {
        this.x = other.getX();
        this.y = other.getY();
    }
```

Comment: Note: If you make your `Point` class immutable, there would be no need to deep copy...

Comment: There are no copy constructors in Java. You can write something similar yourself but what it does is entirely up to you. The compiler doesn't care about them and doesn't have any extra 'settings' for them. I agree entirely with @OliverCharlesworth. You don't need to do this. I've never had to write a 'copy constructor' or use `clone()` in Java in 17 years.

Comment: Change the code of your last constructor to `public Segment(Segment other) { this(other.p1, other.p2); }`. But I also recommend what Oliver suggests.

Comment: snippets are for runnable js, not for java, please remove them

Comment: Thank you everyone! Actually I am following the instructions, which is given to us by our professor and that's why I need to use that code. Thank you Tom, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Almost good. Use this constructor for segment:

```
public Segment(Segment orig)
{
    this(orig.p1, orig.p2);
}
```

Comment: @EJP: No he doesn't, check closely.